# How to add operations into Tensorflow Android build

Tags: java, android, build, tensorflow

I am trying to run my Tensorflow model on Android, so I am using the [nightly native build in here](http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-android/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/out/native/) and following the [Android demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android), I have been successfully get the Tensorflow Android lib running and loaded up the model with below code.

```
inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(getAssets(), MODEL_FILE);
```

And the log shows the results are good.

```
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded TensorFlow native methods (RunStats error may be ignored)
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Model load took 1007ms, TensorFlow version: 1.2.0-rc0
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded model from 'file:///android_asset/model.pb'
```

However, when I finished feeding all the input nodes

```
inferenceInterface.feed("input1", new int[]{1, 2, 3}, 1, 3);
inferenceInterface.feed("input2", new int[]{3}, 1);
inferenceInterface.feed("input3", new int[]{4}, 1);
```

Then call the run method

```
inferenceInterface.run(new String[]{"output"});
```

The Tensorflow is broken saying that some kernels are not registered

```
E/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Failed to run TensorFlow inference with inputs:[input1, input2, input3], outputs:[output]
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ...jnitest, PID: 16357
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'LessEqual' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
<no registered kernels>

[[Node: .../LessEqual = LessEqual[T=DT_INT32](.../maximum_iterations, .../LessEqual/y)]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'LessEqual' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
<no registered kernels>

[[Node: dynamic_seq2seq/decoder/decoder_1/LessEqual = LessEqual[T=DT_INT32](.../maximum_iterations, .../LessEqual/y)]]
at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)
at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:295)
at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:245)
at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:142)
at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:111)
at ...jnitest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
.. 9 more
```

I think the "LessEqual" for int32 should be defined in Tensorflow but just not built along with Tensorflow Android Lib.

**So my question is how to include more kernels in the Android lib build or any other way to resolve this, any help will be much appreciated.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommending reading this free eBook: [Building Mobile Applications with TensorFlow](http://www.oreilly.com/data/free/building-mobile-applications-with-tensorflow.csp)

It has a section on `What Ops Are Available on Mobile?` (page 33), which explains how to `Add the implementation to the build` for those op kernels which default to being stripped out for mobile builds.

FYI, the eBook is written by Pete Warden ([GitHub](https://github.com/petewarden), [blog](https://petewarden.com)), who works at Google and is one of the maintainers of TensorFlow.

Comment: Yes, I read that, and actually problem is resolved by also going through tensorflow source code. And the book is a very good one.

Comment: Hi Dan, I just went through the ebook you had linked. I want to use `DecodeJpeg` op on android. This op isn't included by default.
I have located the implementation of the op, but I can't understand how to include it in the build. The ebook says the implementation files are to be added [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD#L3565) or [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD#L3632). How is that to be done?